# Comparing 2 items but using a value from found item

Tags: sql, ms-access, feed

Having some issues trying to figure out how to write a SQL line to grab a value from an item. Let me explain the situation. We have 2 different databases, one for domestic and one for import. They're the same items just different product codes. The difference is just the international items have a -h at the end. So example..

```
12345   < domestic 
12345-h < import
```

We have a feed going which combines both together but the import items are missing upc codes, while the domestic items have them. So what I wanted to do was have it match both product codes and add the upc to the -h item.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail about the database structure for us to give a good answer, but it should be possible with JOIN.

Comment: Well our original feed comes from various other MS access databases. The master international and domestic database. For our website we have them imported into one database but separated into 2 different queries/tables. When we export them they're combined into a single feed.

Comment: This feed is also submitted to google from our hosting client which is Volusion. So I wanted to just have the website do the join there rather than messing with our other database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a structure like this:

```
select <fields that you want>
from ((select <list of fields from domestic>, itemid as lookupitem
       from domestic d
      ) union all
      (select <list of most fields from import>, replace(itemid, '-h', '') as lookupitem
       from import i
      )
     ) f left join
     lookup lu
     on f.lookupitemid = lu.itemid
```

In other words, you can create the field of the right form in a subquery and then join it to the lookup table used to get UPC.  I use "replace", on the assumption that some codes may not actually end with the "-h".

Comment: I was able to use your suggestions and mix it into the feed and got the items I wanted, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables with

```
 INNER JOIN ON (concat(domestic.itemid, '-h') = international.itemid)
```

You might have to adjust this for the Ms Access SQL dialect. I think for concat you can use &, IIRC.